# "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

**Trigger code -**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tib_ms_merchant_group 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON ms_merchant_group FOR EACH ROW DECLARE integrity_error EXCEPTION; 

PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (integrity_error, -20001); 
errno  INTEGER; 
errmsg CHAR(200); 
dummy  INTEGER; 
FOUND  BOOLEAN; 
BEGIN 
  --  Errors handling 
EXCEPTION 
WHEN integrity_error THEN 
  raise_application_error(errno, errmsg); 
END;
```

**Error -**

```
"PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following: 
:= . ( @ % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "EXCEPTION" to continue."
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should declare some content after the *BEGIN* directive to make the function do something actual? This is (probably) demanded by the SQL syntax. That is why *EXCEPTION* cant be put straight after *BEGIN*

Answer (score 0):

As @sanfor said, you need to have something between the `BEGIN-EXCEPTION` block. I could compile  the trigger -

```
SQL> CREATE
  2  OR
  3  replace TRIGGER tib_ms_merchant_group BEFORE
  4  INSERT
  5  ON emp FOR EACH ROW DECLARE integrity_error EXCEPTION;
  6
  7  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (integrity_error, -20001);
  8  errno  INTEGER;
  9  errmsg CHAR(200);
 10  dummy  INTEGER;
 11  FOUND  BOOLEAN;
 12  BEGIN
 13    NULL;
 14  EXCEPTION
 15  WHEN integrity_error THEN
 16    raise_application_error(errno, errmsg);
 17  END;
 18  /

Trigger created.

SQL> sho err
No errors.
SQL>
```

Just replace the table name and add the required trigger `logic` after `BEGIN`.